# How to handle barcodes with increasing size over time

Tags: mysql, barcode

In my software I have a barcode (`Code39`) for my products like this:

> TypeOfBarcode.ID
>   Example:
>   16.1

`TypeOfBarcode` is a fixed number with a maximum size but `ID` is an autoincrement `int(11)` on `MySql`.

Since `ID` will get bigger and bigger what can I do to have a printed barcode of always the same size ? This barcode is printed on a label of fixed size so it cannot grow beyond a certain dimension.

Should I put some leading in front of my ID ? 
Something like `16.0000001` to have my barcodes always the same size ?

Comment: By 'fixed size' do you mean 'fixed number of characters when displayed'? That is to say, are you asking how to pad your IDs with, say, zeroes?

Comment: Yeah I wan't to have my barcodes always the same size when printed. The leading zeros are just an idea I had, I don't know if maybe that's a better way to handle it

Comment: Why rely on MySQL to format your numbers? You are better to use your language code... otherwise, store as string?

Comment: @alexandre arguably, for the OP's barcode, the IDs really aren't numbers, they really are 16 character strings that happen to be zero padded strings. Enforcing this at the DB means that the ID is independent of the consuming code. This may be preferable.